# Bind enum values to ng-options angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

The response JSON from a http GET method is as shown below

```
 [
    {
        "1": "Open"
    },
    {
        "2": "Expired"
    }
]
```

How to bind this data in a select drop down box in angular js.
I tried with this option:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item for item in data"> 
<option value="">----Select----</option> 
</select>
```

But I'm getting [object,object] in the drop down list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could transform the json data into the format expected by ng-options simply using `Array.reduce`, along the lines of

```
$scope.options = data.reduce(function(memo, obj) {
    return angular.extend(memo, obj);
}, {});

<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="key as val for (key, val) in options"></select>
```

Full example here http://plnkr.co/edit/PV4BYrz0KBkIFPWVzVaT?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

you need a `key,value` in ng-repeat syntax as you have unknown or different keys

And you have to keep track of two repeats first for array and then for keys inside the objects

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selected" > 
<option value="">----Select----</option> 
   <optgroup ng-repeat="v in values">

     <option ng-repeat='(key,value) in v' value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
   </optgroup>  
</select>
```

**Demo**

value in option will be "`open"` or "`expired`" you can change it to keys "`0`" or "`1`" if you replace `value={{value}}` with `value="{{key}}"`

```js
app = angular.module('test',[]);
app.controller('testctrl',function($scope){
$scope.values =[{"1": "Open" },{"2": "Expired" }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="testctrl" ng-app="test">
<span ng-if="selectedModel">{{selectedModel}}</span>
<select class="form-control"  ng-model="selectedModel"> 
<option>----Select----</option> 
   <optgroup ng-repeat="v in values">
     
     <option ng-repeat='(key,value) in v' value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
   </optgroup>  
</select>
  </div>
```

Comment: @A.B.will the value that I select gets binded to the model?

Comment: let me edit, yes this will . can you eloborate your question of comment

Comment: If I want to have the selected name in the model ie., "Expired" if I select the second option.Can I use the model in the controller with te value?

Comment: But why there's a gap between Open and Expired @A.B?

Comment: these are optgroups you can change their style via css or put spans in between editing my answer for model issue

Comment: @MANOJ see i edited, value will be "open" or "expired" you can change it to keys "0" or "1" if you replace value={{value}} with value="{{key}}"